# Website is working on responsive design mode ipad screen but not properly on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Website is working on responsive design mode iPad screen but not properly on ipad
i have checked in all device it is working great but not in ipad.

Here is a [link](http://shreesharanstones.com/).

Comment: Your site is stuck on the preloader graphic when I go look.

Comment: You have a class `device-md` and `device-sm` on your body tag, currently the `device-sm` is applied when the browser reaches 767px, you'll have to change this to 768px for it to work properly on an iPad.

Comment: Need to know what exactly is not working in ipad

Comment: 5 Tiles with different category is not working and they are coming in one by one

Comment: tile section is not working and its is working on responsive mode of Mozilla and chrome but not on ipad

Answer (score -1):

create media query for ipad-pro

```
media@(max-width:1200px) { }
```

for ipad

```
media@(max-width:900px) { }
```

And the bootstrap4 class should be `col-md` or `col-lg`

Comment: I have already applied according to mozilla developer mode . All 5 tiles in middle section is working but not working in ipad  properly .